# Get Array Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have one form that have a select box inside while-loop. I try to get the data or value from that select box. Below is my form code.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="test2.php" >
    <?php 
        $endDate = '2014-01-28';
        $startDate = '2014-01-27';

        $daydiff = floor( ( strtotime( $endDate ) - strtotime( $startDate ) ) / 86400 );

        $x=0; 
        while($x<=$daydiff)
        {
            ?>
                <select class="form-control" name="day_<?php echo $x; ?>">
                    <option value="monday">Monday</option>
                    <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                    <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                    <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
                </select>
                <select class="form-control" name="time_<?php echo $x; ?>">
                    <option value="10am">10am</option>
                    <option value="11am">11am</option>
                    <option value="12pm">12pm</option>
                    <option value="1pm">1pm</option>
                </select>
            <?php
            $x++;
        } 
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo $x ?>"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Below is my "test2.php".

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['count']; $i++){
    $day_var = 'day_' . $i;
    $days_list[] = $_POST[$day_var];

    $time_var = 'time_' . $i;
    $time_list[] = $_POST[$time_var];

    echo ($_POST[$day_var]);
    echo ($_POST[$time_var]);
}

?>
```

When I submit it will echo "monday10tuesday11am" how can I extract the value separately i.e. `monday10` and `tuesday11am`?

Comment: Didn't you already collect the values in two arrays?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes its true, I already get value in two arrays. How can I extract the value? means should I use Explode or something else? When I echo it will be like this "monday 10am tuesday 11am"

Comment: which value are you talking about can you please add expected result.

Comment: I believe you have just created an imaginary problem. Why don't you just try
    
    `echo $_POST[$day_var]."<br>";
    echo $_POST[$time_var]."<br>";`

And you should learn the first step of PHP which is to learn the echo function... right ?

Comment: Thank you!! I need to learn more about PHP. But if I want to insert into MySQL how it will be?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your numbering scheme and variable variables with a simple array in HTML.

```
<select class="form-control" name="day[<?php echo $x; ?>]">
<select class="form-control" name="time[<?php echo $x; ?>]">

$days_list[] = $_POST[$day];
$time_list[] = $_POST[$time];
```

This would greatly simplify your form2.php. Otherwise, please try to explain what results you are expecting with the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

just add some space to your echo.

```
echo ($_POST[$day_var]).' '.($_POST[$time_var]);
```

Comment: also you can use html encoding  echo ($_POST[$day_var]).'&nbsp;'.($_POST[$time_var]);

Comment: Thank you!! But if I want to insert the value into MySQL how it will be?

Comment: you mean the whole thing? "monday 10am tuesday 11am" into one column?

Comment: if so save that as a string in a variable and use that variable in insert or update statement. $var = ($_POST[$day_var]).' '.($_POST[$time_var]);

Comment: I want to monday in one column, 10am in one column and so on? how it will be?

Comment: you have saved it in array $days_list[] = $_POST[$day_var]; $time_list[] = $_POST[$time_var]; use it in a loop and execute the query.

Comment: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Insert-Multiple-Rows-Into-MySQL-The-Right-Way-With-PHP.html

Comment: Thank you! I forget to use loop. Thanks again.